# How can I call Imagemagick's compare command using java without using Runtime.exec() function

Tags: java, imagemagick, jmagick

I am writing a java utility which will convert jbig images into png format.
     I am using jmagick api which is an open source Java interface of ImageMagick.
     I did't find any compare function api in [jmagick](http://www.jmagick.org/index.html;jsessionid=FBD310DFB234AEAFD0B9564EA783F7C3) so I am unable to call [ImageMagick's](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) compare command using this [jmagick][3].
Can anybody give me any other workaround instead of calling directly from java using Runtime.exec() method.
Thanks in advance